# Perl IRC Bot running on the machine

Tags: linux, perl, irc

I had someone hacked into my linux machine and was running a perl code which seems to be some kind of a bot. The next day I got a call from ISP saying that there are large number of spam mails eminating from your IP address. I found this perl code in my home dir.

[Perl IRC Bot](http://topgun.do.am/TopGun/1.txt)

Can you please help me find out what this code does and what are the damages to my system.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3):

(Yes, it dosen't answer what he's asking. Its answering *what he needs to know*)

Nuke it from orbit... Its the only way to be sure. You can't really trust a compromised system and your problems are more than the perl bot.

It happens though, but *what you know about* is merely the tip of the iceburg.

So... Backup. Right now. I mean it. In my case I did a file level dump of my entire filesystem to a windows box, and ran a AV scan on it - which found a virus. Imaging the drive would be more fun, but imaging a remote VPS seemed like a recipie for pain at the point of time.

Reinstall your OS.Yes, its a pain but you don't know what's been done.

Set up remote access the *right* way. Set up key based authentication. Disable root access via ssh. Use a non standard port. If you want, install fail2ban and set it up.

Now, lets talk about *investigation*. Depending on the flavour of linux you run, you can probably track down the IP addresses the attacker connected from. Its *entirely* useless since the attacker could be using another compromised system but its probably handy if you want to temporarily block him at the firewall. You'll need to sort through the entries in /var/log/audit/audit.log in redhatealikes and /var/log/auth.log in ubuntu based distros - grep might work but explaining how to do it is a whole another book.

You could also use this to find when the attacker came in and maybe check what files were changed around then - [this U&L question seems like a good start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185897/find-files-based-on-modified-datespecifying-the-exact-hour).

The fact that its an apparently copy-pasted script suggests that the attacker isn't terribly skilled. Its good since damage is limited, but bad in the sense that he might not actually know what all his tools do.

Answer (score 2):

It will connect you to an IRC server defined in the `$server` variable, enter you to the `#ddos` channel and accept any command by those defined in the `@admins` array.

Indeed, what your ISP says is more than likely as there is a `mail` command, so you likely became a spammer controlled by those who hacked you.

There are many other commands allowing to do lots of things, as you don't have a log file of what they actually run I would consider that machine not reliable and reinstall it (I would do a research on how you got hacked first, though), as they even have a command to run *any* shell command.

You can first bring down the network interface so you don't cause any harm so you can then enter locally and try to find out what happened.